# Variation of the Chinese Postman Problem_

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

In order to be well prepared for my spring quarter exams right now I'm studying and experimenting with graph problems.

I already got familiar to typical problems like the "Traveling Salesman" but when I took a deeper look into the "chinese postman problem" and its variations I immediately felt like an important aspect of the problem was missing: The aspect of having a limited capacity, thus the need to return to the office station after a certain number *n* of letters is successfully delivered (in order to get new ones). What about finding the shortest path then?

I was very intrigued with the CPP because of its relevancy and easy applicability for real  life but I think adding this aspect would make it even more real life applicable.

I would be thankful for any help on how to find the shortest path in an undirected graph that visits every edge at least once (CPP) the the constraint of having to return to the starting point (post station) after a certain number of letters is delivered.

---

EDIT (description of originial CPP): 
"The chinese postman problem or route inspection problem is to find a shortest closed path or circuit that visits every edge of a (connected) undirected graph. When the graph has an 
Eulerian circuit (a closed walk that covers every edge once), that circuit is an optimal solution. 
If the graph is not Eulerian, it must contain vertices of odd degree. By the handshaking lemma, there must be an even number of these vertices. To solve the postman problem we first find a smallest T-join. We make the graph Eulerian by doubling of the T-join. The solution to the postman problem in the original graph is obtained by finding an Eulerian circuit for the new graph."
Src: wikipedia.org

Comment: [These word filters have got to go...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)

Comment: Please provide a description of the problem or a link to a good description of it...

Comment: *"I'd like to hear your thoughts about the problem.*"  Is not a proper question.  If you do not ask a proper programming question, you'll get closed by the community.  The StackExchange forums are Q+A forums.  They are not discussion forums and they are definitely not set up for it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, RBarryYoung. Question edited.

Answer (score 2):

Your variant is NP-hard by a reduction from, e.g., the [3-partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) where all values are strictly between B/4 and B/2. It might be "solved" using some of the same methods as [capacitated vehicle routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem). You have to understand, though, that CPP is less a real problem than an excuse to study T-joins.

Comment: One application is in testing, where the nodes are states, and you want to exercise every state transition. Admitedly, I can't think of a second myself, although http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~castello/251/Handouts/ChinesePostman.doc claims that it really is useful for inspecting or servicing real life roads and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, oldboy. Nevertheless, I still do not really find any problem similar to the one I posted above when browsing through the different variations of capacitated vehicle routing problems.

Comment: If you're trying to minimize total distance, there's no difference between multiple vehicles and a single vehicle making multiple trips. The CVRP is to serve all client *vertices* (instead of edges) with limited-capacity vehicles. One possible reduction from your problem to CVRP is to put clients in the middle of each edge.

Comment: I guess that only works with directed edges, but my overall point is, your problem has the same blend of partitioning the clients between trips and navigating between clients.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess you are right about multi-vehicles = single-vehicle aspect if the "costs" one is trying to minimize doesn'T depend on the time. 
Still I don't really know whether the CVRP is applicable for the edges of a graph, too.